# How to Define Product in WooCommerce Shortcode to use on Custom Order Received Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I am trying to understand how to define product in this code after having made some changes to it based on the answer in my previous question [Why does WooCommerce Order Shortcode Generate Plugin Notice on Custom Thank You Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335767/why-does-woocommerce-order-shortcode-generate-plugin-notice-on-custom-thank-you)

The notice message have changed and now it asks me to define product. **This is the notice**:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: product in /wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 842
```

**The notice refers to this line:**

```
'purchase_note' => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
```

**This is the full code:**

```
function order_cost_breakdown(){

    if ( isset( $_GET['order_id']) && $_GET['order_id'] > 0 ) {

        $order_id = (int) esc_attr( $_GET['order_id'] );

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        $order_data = $order->get_data();

        $show_purchase_note    = $order->has_status( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_purchase_note_order_statuses', array( 'completed', 'processing' ) ) );

    ob_start();
    
    ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-account woocommerce-page"><div class="woocommerce">

            <table class="shop_table order_details">

                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                        <th class="product-total"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>

                    </tr>

                </thead>

            <tbody>

        <?php foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array (
        'order' => $order,
        'item_id' => $item_id,
        'item' => $item,
        'product' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $item->get_product( $item ), $item ),
        'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
        'purchase_note' => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
        ) );
        }
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_items_table', $order ); ?>

            </tbody>
        
        <tfoot>

    <?php

        foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ){
    ?>

    <tr>
    
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
    </tr>

        <?php
    }

    ?>
            </tfoot>
    
        </table>
    
    </div>

</div>

<?php

    return ob_get_clean();
    
    }

}
```

Any advice is helpful as I am clearly not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the notice

Replace

```php
<?php foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array (
    'order' => $order,
    'item_id' => $item_id,
    'item' => $item,
    'product' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $item->get_product( $item ), $item ),
    'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
    'purchase_note' => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
    ) );
    }
?>
```

With

```php
<?php foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();

    wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array (
        'order'              => $order,
        'item_id'            => $item_id,
        'item'               => $item,
        'product'            => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $item->get_product( $item ), $item ),
        'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
        'purchase_note'      => $product ? $product->get_purchase_note() : '',
    ));
}       
?>
```

---

That should suffice

Comment: It did! Thank you so much :)